# How to fall back to a google web font if the user doesn't have eg helvetica installed

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I want a font to 'fall back' to a certain font on google web fonts (Open Sans) if the user doesn't have helvetica installed, is there a simple way of doing this?

My idea is that i only want the user to have to download the font if they have to, eg for mac users i don't want them to have to download the font.

Eg, something like this, if possible:

```
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Open Sans Light', Arial;
```

Also, since i'm using the specific light version of helvetica 'Helvetica Neue Light', when falling back to open sans / arial is there a way of specifying the font weight in such a way that the weight only applies to the fallback font? Does the following do that?

```
h1 { font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Arial; font-weight: 400; }
```

Comment: If you use the Google Font API, it should do that for yo... ie. tell the API to include it and it should determine if the user has the font or not

Comment: But google web font's don't include helvetica due to licensing, so i want it to fall over to another font on another weight. Possible easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a local path to the font inside the [@font-face src property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-webfonts/#src-desc), so clients who already have the font won't download it from the alternate source. I don't know how well it's supported across browsers, but it should work with any browser that has font-face support.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  src: local(Helvetica), url(/path/to/Helvetica.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Will that allow it to fall back to open sans (or another font)? I mean, i can't simply upload helvetica to my site...

Comment: Yes, just specify whatever font in the `url()` and that will be what is used if they don't have the specified font locally.